# China visa application: arrival flight connects to a domestic flight. Which flight number do I put down?

Tags: visas, china

I am a British citizen filling out a visa application form for China, but I am struggling on what to put as my flight number for my arrival flight as it is from the Philippines and contains two flights. The first is from Manila to Guangzhou, and then a second flight from Guangzhou to Wuxu Airport in Nanning.
I'm concerned that if I put the second flight number that it won't look like it's my arrival flight on the application form, but if I put the first flight number, will I have to validate my visa on entry at Guangzhou?

Comment: Won't you have to go through immigration, validating your visa, to get from an international arrival to a domestic departure at Guangzhou anyway?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan yes that is correct

Comment: Imagine a US citizen were flying from San Diego to Edinburgh, changing planes at Heathrow, SAN->LHR->EDI, on a single booking. They would go through immigration and customs at Heathrow, and that would be their point of entry. The domestic LHR->EDI flight would also have people just traveling from London to Edinburgh, and have no immigration checks on arrival at Edinburgh.

Comment: Have you checked out the 144 hour(5 days) visa free transit if you're not there long?

Answer (score 10):

Put the first flight which takes you into China. You will have to pass through immigrations in order to get to the domestic gate for your second flight.

You may also have to re-check your checked-in luggage as well.

So you list the flight that brings you into China from abroad, you do not list the domestic flight as you do not need a visa for domestic flights these days

Comment: No, they're referring to Nanning Wuxu Airport: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanning_Wuxu_International_Airport

Comment: @lambshaanxy ok it wont change anything though

Comment: I upvoted you, but you might wish to make it clearer that they should list the first flight, where they actually arrive in China, on the application form.

Comment: When I went to China the visa application asked for my itinerary. I did list internal flights there. I don't know whether that is still required.

Answer (score 6):

The first flight, so the flight which define your port of entry (and times), in case they need to check you.

Comment: In case? Of course they will check when you pass immigrations

Comment: Check and cancel your entry so it cannot be used again.  OP is not transiting.  On a two entry visa they would cancel each entry in turn.

Comment: I should edit my answer (later). I was stopped, but in short: they found you are possibly a criminal (from records, e.g. same name), maybe someone will check you (your face) to see if you were the searched one. Port of entry keeps your paperwork: if you misbehave, they may check original paper, to find an excuse to ban you. "Excuse" because it is not the real reason, but probably the most efficient way. Don't be scared about this, this is for bad guys.